# Relacement type defination for SQLHANDLE instead of void *

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, com, odbc

For **64 bit Windows** and **odbc version > 3.0**, `sqltypes.h` defines SQLHANDLE as

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
typedef void*                   SQLHANDLE;
#else
```

If you need to marshal this variable through COM

```
[id(1)] HRESULT SQLAllocHandle([in] SQLSMALLINT HandleType, [in] SQLHANDLE InputHandle, [out] SQLHANDLE* OutputHandle, [out,retval] SQLRETURN* rc);
```

you would receive a compile error

```
error MIDL2139: type of the parameter cannot derive from void or void *
```

What would be the appropriate replacement typedef for SQLHANDLE I can use in this scenario?

Comment: Midl allows `void*` and `void**` parameters. How do you get this error?

Comment: If the headers tell you a `SQLHANDLE` is a `void *`, what makes you think that you can "marshal it" at all? Check the documentation to make sure you are allowed to use the handle from any thread in your process without any synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, as I was using ATL, I redefined the SQLHANDLE as OLE_HANDLE. This enabled a transparent synchronization between the Client and the Server Process.

Answer (score 0):

The common technique for passing any type of `HANDLE`, be it `HWND` or whatever, via COM is to cast it to `long`.